# PyTorch equivalent of a Tensorflow linear layer

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I was trying to reimplement a Tensorflow code using PyTorch framework. Below I have included the TF sample code and my PyT interpretation.

TensorFlow implementation:

```
W1 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([135, 128]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[128]))

def fcn(x):
    z = tf.reshape(x, (-1, 135))
    out1 = leaky_relu( tf.matmul(z, W1) + b1 )

    return out1
```

PyTorch implementation:

```
class decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(decoder, self).__init__()

        self.layer_10 = nn.Linear(135, 128, bias=True)
        self.leaky = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=False)
        init.xavier_uniform(self.layer_10.weight) 

    def forward(self, x):
        z = x.view(-1, 135)
        h30 = self.leaky(self.layer_10(z))

        return h30
```

I was wondering what is the proper way to implement the `matmul` part, given that the weights in pytorch are not explicitly defined as they are in the TF (or correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to *explicitly* call [`torch.matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.matmul): it is in the implementation of the `forward` method of the `nn.Linear` layer. By calling `self.layer_10(z)` you are actually calling (behind the scene) the `forward` method that does the matrix multiplication and adds the bias for you.

If you want your code to be exactly the same, you might want to explicitly initialize the weights using the same method. For that you have `nn.init` that implements a variety of weight initializations. Specifically, you might find [`nn.init.xavier_uniform_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html#torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_) relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, does the weight initialization look good now?

Comment: @Blade for this you'll need to see what `xavier_init` does in tensor flow and see if it matches the defaults of pytorch. I do not know the exact behavior by heart.

Comment: Thanks. For future reader's reference, that's the way the second example in: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/108253/torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform did it